# How to debug in acceptDrop method of Outline View in swift MAC OS?

Tags: swift, macos, macos-catalina

I'm working on the **outline** view in mac OS swift. I want to debug in this method when an item is dropped on it. But, the app got stuck when I added a breakpoint in this method. 
I have tried debugging using log also, but is there any other way to do so?

Here is the method I'm working on.

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, item: Any?, childIndex index: Int) -> Bool {

}
```

Comment: "the app got stuck when I added a breakpoint in this method" Isn't that what a breakpoint does?

Comment: Tip: Move all app windows out of the way so you can see the source code before you start dragging.

Comment: @Sweeper it doesn't stop on the breakpoint. Rather, It stops my app and I've to reopen my app again.

Comment: have you find any solution ? is there any method that is rining in background?

Comment: @AwaisMobeen No, I didn't find any solution yet except log.

Comment: Does the app stop or does the app get stuck? Does the app get stuck without the breakpoint?

Comment: @Willeke only If I add a breakpoint in this method. Then my app stops working and I have to forcefully quit it.

Comment: Does the Pause button in Xcode work?

Comment: @Willeke no, my app and Xcode both stop working.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project?